# Libraries missing in eclipse after building with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, import

So, I just started working on a huge project, I was told to download and build Maven3 and clone project from Git repository.

My understanding is that Maven is supposed to import all libraries used in project, automatically.

Now, Maven builds project without errors, but when I opened project in Eclipse, bunch of libraries is missing, not all of them but like 1/4 - 1/3.

I'm pretty new to this, so maybe this question is stupid and i did something wrong or understand something wrong. But i would appreciate help.

**EDIT**

So the problem was that when i was importing project from Git, i chose Java Project, instead of Maven Project.

**EDIT2**

When I imported project as Maven Project I came upon another problem. Libraries were still not correctly imported. I found various solutions here but none helped. I finally found out that I'm dumb as f**k and I was chosing root directory as a root directory for whole repository while the correct pom was like 2 dirs inside it. So i was building from the wrong pom.. I blame the fact that yesterday I didn't know what Maven is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have downloaded the dependencies successfully from the MAVEN, you just need to update it with the project in Eclipse.

Use following option in Eclipse

```
Right Click Project > MAVEN > Update Project..
```

Comment: if I dont have MAVEN option there? but there is Convert to Maven .. should i do that first?

Comment: then you need to add Eclipse plugin for that

Comment: yes.convert to maven project.. then you will see maven option

Comment: Did you create your project as maven project?

Comment: Under **Configure** there is **Convert to Maven** option. Isnt that sufficient?

Comment: The thing is that when I was importing project from Git i selected Java Project. I think I have to import project again as Maven Project. Correct?